# Android Button Can't Start Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm having a bit of an issue with my android button. When I press it, my app crashes, and in my logcat, I have the following error:

```
Caused by android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.defendthecastle/com.example.defendthecastle.GameView}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

The weird thing is that the activity that I'm starting when I click my button isn't GameView, it's GameActivity (which uses GameView as its View). I didn't have the activity declared in my manifest before, so I did that, but I'm still getting the same error.
This is how I set up my button:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View startButton = findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.start_button:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

And here is the button in my xml:

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:id="@+id/start_button"

    />
```

Lastly, here is my GameActivity class:

```
package com.example.defendthecastle;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    GameView gameView = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gameView);
    gameView.requestFocus();
}

}
```

I know it's not an issue with my GameView because I tried using another view from another app which I know works. This is really frustrating because it's just an issue with my button. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post your manifest

Comment: show your `manifest`

Comment: What is the first class you have here? `MainActivity`? Show the Manifest as well as the `GameView` class. It is unclear why the system thinks you are trying to start that view as an Activity

Comment: @LLK have try my answer?

Answer (score -1):

**Declare you Activity in Manifest file too otherwise it will not called.**

**Note:** And sure it should be in application tag of Manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.defendthecastle.GameView"/>
```

Comment: Read the error again. That is the wrong class.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but the post explicitly states that class is a view, not an Activity class

Comment: if its view not a activity then why android.content.ActivityNotFoundException is shown with `GameView` name

Comment: That's the question the post is trying to figure out :)